# error, i try building angular proyect and get this

Tags: angular

Error in building my project ,when I try to upload my site to the web and do the build I get this error

\main.component.html(3,7): : Property 'isHandset$' does not exist on type 'MainComponent'.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menú</mat-toolbar>   
    <mat-nav-list>
       <ng-template let-item let-last="last" ngFor [ngForOf]="routes">
                        <a mat-list-item    [routerLink]="[item.route]"
                                            [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                                            [routerLink]="">
                        <mat-icon class="tc-blue-grey-700">{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>  &nbsp;
                        {{item.title}}
                      </a>

        </ng-template>
```

Comment: Post the code of the component..

Comment: I mean... the error is pretty clear. You have no isHandset in mainComponent..

Answer (score 0):

This is an error because of the isHandset$ has not been declared in your main component.

After declaration this error would not occur